# water company replaced meter now very low water pressure!

Tags: water-pressure

I recently came home from work to find the water company digging up my front yard.  Apparently they were putting in a new meter? An hour or so after they left i turned my kitchen sink on and water came sputtering out- I'm assuming there was air mixed in the water. I turned it off and on again the water was dirty then cloudy for a few hours but had very little pressure!! We used to have amazing pressure. I cleaned all the filter screens on every faucet in the house-they had dirt and debris caked in them-water pressure is a little better but nowhere close to what it was. Replaced the shower heads and have had a plumber come 4 times because water company of course is saying its not their fault or problem!?! Still terribly low pressure.  IT takes 20 mins to fill the bath tub and taking a shower is almost torture there's so little water pressure!! Now my washing machine sounds like there's dirt or sand inside it and shut itself down mid load and won't work!! What do we do? is this the water company's fault? Plumber cannot get to whatever is clogging or causing the problem. Please help

Comment: I recommend that you arm yourself with some actual facts and figures.  Start with measuring the water pressure at the meter (your side of it) with all the water shut off and with something typical happening like the shower or the tub filling.  Then find out what their standard for service pressure is and go from there.

Comment: Do you have a pressure regulator at the house, or a secondary cold water shutoff valve, these could be filled with rust,  scale or even pipe tape restricting the flow prior to your faucets.

Comment: if the pressure is low you will be able to easily stop the flow with your thumb, if there is a costriction the flow will be slow, but difficult to stop.

Comment: Suggestion:  Get a pressure gauge (HD or Lowes in the irrigation dept.) that connects to a hose bib on the house (assuming the hose bib is not independent of the house's internal plumbing).   Take a pressure reading with nothing running. Then turn on a bath tub or other faucet or two and take another reading.  If there is a large difference, you have an obstruction someplace.  Probably debris from the meter installation. IMHO.  Adding one more thought:  Depending upon where the obstruction might be, this method may or may not work.   But at least you'll know what the pressure is.